# Operator overload for std::array template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, operator-overloading

I want a simple way of having a fixed-size array of floats to be elementwise multiplied with one another.  I've written the following code to try to implement this:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template <uint16_t N>
using color = std::array<float,N>;

template <uint16_t N>
constexpr color<N> operator* (color<N> lhs, const color<N>& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        lhs[i] *= rhs[i];
    }
    return lhs;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr uint16_t N = 10;

    color<N> myColor{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    color<N> myColor2{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
    
    color<N> mult = myColor * myColor2;

    return 0;
};
```

When compiled with gcc, I get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:23:29: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘color<10>’ {aka ‘std::array<float, 10>’} and ‘color<10>’ {aka ‘std::array<float, 10>’})
   23 |     color<N> mult = myColor * myColor2;
      |                     ~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
      |                     |         |
      |                     |         array<[...],[...]>
      |                     array<[...],[...]>
test.cpp:8:20: note: candidate: ‘template<short unsigned int N> constexpr color<N> operator*(color<N>, color<N>&)’
    8 | constexpr color<N> operator* (color<N> lhs, const color<N>& rhs)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:8:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:23:31: note:   mismatched types ‘short unsigned int’ and ‘long unsigned int’
   23 |     color<N> mult = myColor * myColor2;
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way of having a template of an operator overload?  Or is there a more sensible way of going about this?

Comment: If you don't actually need fixed size supoprt, [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) already does this.

Comment: generally you shouldnt overload operators for standard library types. Though the error is interesting

Comment: @Chris Gnam The second template parameter of the class std::array has the type size_t.

Comment: It is not recommended to do this. You should represent color as new type instead. The issue with doing it this way if you aren't just defining `*` for colors, you are defining it for all arrays of floats. It will cause problems if you or someone else on the project uses this approach to model something different.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ahh that makes sense.  The most immediately obvious solution would be create a class which contains `std::array` as a member.  Is this the recommended approach?  Would deriving from `std::array` be better or worse?

Comment: @ChrisGnam Deriving from any `std` container comes with traps and is generally discouraged. The simplest solution is something like `class color { public: std::array<float, N> data; };`. Arguably a more convenient solution would be to encapsulate the data further and make the data private and adding proper interface functions.

Answer (score 6):

`uint16_t` is not the correct type. `std::array` uses `std::size_t` for `N`, so if you want to use `std::array` then use `std::size_t`:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^
using color = std::array<float, N>;

template <std::size_t N>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^
constexpr color<N> operator* (color<N> lhs, const color<N>& rhs)
```